# How to add my browser in the default browser selection list in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a app called "TextOnly" ..How to add in the list to select default browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify your intent in the android manifest file such as:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="http"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

make sure:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

is in there too.

[reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#iobjs):

> Similarly, if the action is ACTION_VIEW and the data field is an http: URI, the receiving activity would be called upon to download and display whatever data the URI refers to.

Comment: Even after adding this I am not able to see my app in the default browsers lists. Is there any other criteria in addition to these changes in manifest file?