# My browser is not showing up in the default list

Tags: android

I have a problem relate to my "TextOnly" Browser for Android regarding browser in the list.I added this code from this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394369/how-to-add-my-browser-in-the-default-browser-selection-list-in-android)

```
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:scheme="http"/> 
   </intent-filter>
```

But the problem now is it shows up in the list only when links are opened from Twitter..when links are opened from Facebook it's not showing up..but other browsers (Opera,Skyfire) are getting displayed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `<data android:scheme="https"/>` is missing?

Comment: Exactly..that's the cause..Thanks!!